# How to store 3 different results within the same function

Tags: javascript

I`m working on a rock/paper/scissors game using javascript, the player will play 3 times, and the results of each time will be displayed on screen.Every play is stored in a different function that returns a value. The final result will be given according to the sum of those 3 values.

I am having problems to figure out the logic to play those 3 times in the same button.

After I pressed a button and play by the first time, how can I press it again, but play a second function? Should I use only 1 function but how could I store 3 different results?

```js
function playGame(choice) {


confirm('Are you sure?');
 document.getElementById("userChoice1").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/rock2.png')";  
 document.getElementById("userChoice2").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/scissors2.png')";  
 document.getElementById("userChoice3").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/paper2.png')";  

   if(choice == 'A')
   {
      var userChoice = "rock";  
    /* animation   */   
      document.getElementById("userChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/rock.png')";  
   }
   else if(choice ==  'B')
   {
      var userChoice = "scissors";   
   /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("userChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/scissors.png')";  
   } else if (choice ==  'C'){
      var userChoice = "paper";  
     /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("userChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/paper.png')";  
   }

var computerChoice = Math.random();
if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
 computerChoice = "rock";
 /* animation   */ 
 document.getElementById("aiChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/rock.png')";  
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
 computerChoice = "paper";
 /* animation   */ 
 document.getElementById("aiChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/paper.png')";  
} else {
 computerChoice = "scissors";
 /* animation   */ 
 document.getElementById("aiChoiceDis").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/scissors.png')"; 
} 

var compare1 = function(choice1, choice2) {

    if(choice1 === choice2) {
     document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/tie.png')"; 
  var pResult = "tie";
  document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
      
    }else if(choice1 ==="rock")
    {
        if(choice2 === "scissors")
        {
      /* animation   */ 
   
            document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/win.png')"; 
    
   /* animation   */ 
   document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
   var pResult =  true;
   
        }else
        {
      /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/loose.png')"; 
   
   /* animation   */ 
            document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
   var pResult =  false;
        }
    }else if(choice1 ==="paper")
    {
        if(choice2 === "rock")
        {
      /* animation   */ 
   document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/win.png')"; 
   var pResult = true;
   /* animation   */ 
   document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
        }else
        {
       /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/loose.png')"; 
   var pResult = false;
   /* animation   */ 
   document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
        }
    }else if(choice1 ==="scissors")
    {
        if(choice2 === "rock")
        {
      /* animation   */ 
            document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/loose.png')"; 
   var pResult = false;
   /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
   
        }else
        {
      /* animation   */ 
      document.getElementById("result").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/win.png')"; 
   var pResult = true;
   /* animation   */ 
   document.getElementById("replay").style.display = "block";  
        }
    }else
    {
         return "incorrect input";
    }
 
 switch(pResult) {
    case true:
        document.getElementById("gameResult1").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/win.png')";
        break;
    case "tie":
        document.getElementById("gameResult1").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/win.png')";
        break;
    default:
        document.getElementById("gameResult1").style.backgroundImage = "url('./img/loose.png')";
  
}
 
};
compare1(userChoice,computerChoice);
```

Comment: Put some code buddy ..

Comment: Please share the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an array - Each time use something like:

```
var allResults = []; //declare the array
allResults.push(results);
```

Then you will have a nice array of all the results. You can inspect the contents of the array with `console.log(allResults)`. To access the individual results, use an index number, for example `allResults[0]` will return the first value in the array.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so every new result will be pushed into the allResults array? Let me try it!

Comment: So, I should declare var allResults = []; outside my compare1 function, but where and how should I push the its results?

Comment: Yes, declare it outside, so it doesn't get erased (reinitialized) every time the function runs. Are you just storing whether it's a win/lose/tie? If so, I would do it in your switch statement `case true: allResults.push("win");` etc.

Comment: Great! I fixed it, but before I close this post, I will do some changes in my code.

Comment: @FernandoSouza, would you mind marking as correct/upvoting if it was helpful? Thanks!